# Intent context to view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-context

Estoy con una aplicación para el colegio que consiste en una aplicación de coctelería y recetas.

Dentro de ésta tengo varias activities que funcionan correctamente con sus intents para pasar de una a otra, claro que también tengo list view's con sus adaptadores para hacer el trabajo mas ameno.

El caso está en cuando he creado un sencillo intent de una actividad principal que acabo de crear que hará la función de menú.La aplicación se cierra automáticamente al detectar que esa actividad tiene un intent que va a una actividad con list view.

El caso es que todas las activities tienen intents igual de simples pero no dan ningún tipo de fallo, pero si las modifico para que tengan un botón que pase a otra activity, ésta da problemas también.

Dándole vueltas he encontrado el fallo:

El botón creado me dice:

> Button (android.content.context) in button canot be appiled to
>   (andorid.view.View)

Al compilar con el error me muestra:

> error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Context
>           Button coctel = new Button(findViewById(R.id.buttonCoc));

Como puedo hacer el intent para poder ver la activity que deseo?

Comment: El problema se provoca al crear el botón seguramente debes usar únicamente : findViewById, ejemplo: Button coctel = findViewById(R.id.buttonCoc);

Answer (score 0):

El problema se provoca al crear el botón, los dos errores indican el problema:

> Button (android.content.context) in button canot be appiled to
>   (android.view.View)
>
> error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Context Button
>   coctel = new Button(findViewById(R.id.buttonCoc));

debes usar el contexto para crear el botón, pero en este caso, si el botón existe en el layout (lo cual es lo más probable) debes usar:

```
 Button coctel = findViewById(R.id.buttonCoc);
```

---

de otra forma usa el contexto para poder crear un botón:

```
  Button coctel = new Button(getApplicationContext());
```